# MSBuild Package Generation enclosing xpath in double quotes

Tags: xpath, msbuild, msdeploy

I'm generating a deploy package for my project by using the following script

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe" MyProjectFile.csproj /t:Clean;Build;Package /p:Configuration="Debug" /m /P:Platform=AnyCPU
```

I've also added an MsDeploySkipRules item to skip over empty directories when the package is deployed, which is added in a custom skip actions target i've build.

```
<Target Name="AddSkipActions" AfterTargets="GenerateSkipRuleForAppData">
  <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipEmptyDirectories">
    <SkipAction></SkipAction>
    <ObjectName></ObjectName>
    <AbsolutePath></AbsolutePath>
    <XPath>dirPath[count^(*^)=0]</XPath>        
  </MsDeploySkipRules>
```

The problem i'm experience is when the package is created, it's wrapping the xpath expression in double quotes within the deploy command file, like so:

```
 -skip:xpath="dirPath[count^(*^)=0]"
```

When i run the command, i recieve the following error:

```
Error: 'dirPath[count^(*^)=0]' has an invalid token.
```

I can fix this by modifying the command file manually to the following:

```
-skip:xpath='dirPath[count^(*^)=0]'
```

Any ideas on how to fix the way the package is generated to use single quotes in place of double quotes - i've googled like crazy, but can't seem to find the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, it was the exe used to generate the package.

I changed the msbuild path to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" and after fixing some errors, it's now generating the xpath parameter in single quotes.